# Counting lines containing specific values in a text file

Tags: java, file-io, infinite-loop

I'm trying to count the lines containing specific types of values in a text file and store the result in a variable for later use elsewhere. However, I keep getting stuck in an infinite loop. The file only has a `double` value on the first line, and then a `String`, an `int`, and a `double` (in that order) on each line after that. I'm only trying to count the number of lines containing `String` values, and then use this count elsewhere in my code. I thought that a do-while loop with the condition `file.hasNextLine()` would be the best solution.

The file name is passed in from another method, and then opened in the `displayItemMenu(..)` method, but I'm fairly certain the file is being read in correctly as the first `double` in the file is outputted properly.

```
public static int displayItemMenu (String fileName, int choice) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    File inputFile = new File (fileName);
    Scanner file = new Scanner (inputFile); 
    double currentBalance = file.nextDouble();
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    boolean invalid = false;
    int fileLines = 0;
    int actionChoice = 0;

    System.out.println ("choice: " + choice);

    do 
    {
        fileLines++;
    } while (file.hasNextLine());

    System.out.println ("FileLines: " + fileLines);

    for (int i = 0; i < fileLines; i++)
    {
        if (choice == fileLines)
        {
            String item = file.next();
            int quantity = file.nextInt();
            double price = file.nextDouble();
            file.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
do {
    fileLines++;
}while (file.hasNextLine());
```

You're not reading any line, so you're always at the first line of the file. Change it to this:

```
while (file.hasNextLine()) {
    fileLines++;
    file.nextLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `file.nextLine()`;
The `file.hasNextLine()` only checks if there's one more file but doesn't move the pointer.

I recommend you to change the do while for a while because if there isn't an new line `file.nextLine()` will throw a exception